# Is there a JSON format for editing JSON?

Tags: json

I'm wondering if there is a JSON format for editing JSON ?

eg if I had some json

```
{ "first name" : "Joe" }
```

and + another json file

```
{ "action" : "add",
  "dest"   : "root"  -- json pointer maybe
  "value"  : { "surname : "Blogs" } 
}
```

would get me =

```
{ "first name" : "Joe", "surname : "Blogs" }
```

similarly a delete , and change ..

Is there a JSON format that does this? It may be part of a noSQL db or may not be or some javascript library - but i'm not after a JS library more is there a JSON format to do this,  One would assume someone has done this before!

Comment: cool idea!! would be great if somebody had already implemented it already +1 for the concept but I am afraid such a library wouldn't offer much customization.

Comment: yes just a cool idea!, very basic at this stage i think i'll call it MASON ( Modifiable JSON , JSON + MASON = JSON - heard it here first.

Comment: In XML world, there is a protocol call XCAP could achieve what you require.  But XCAP is designed based on the strict nature of XML, like XPATH and XML schema. JSON has no formal equivalent  stuff, I doubt whether it is applicable to design a well-defined format for JSON of XCAP-similar standard.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a DSL (domain specific language) for tranforming JSON, of which you can find several with a web search for "DSL for json transformation".   [jolt](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) would seem to meet your requirements

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like that.  JSON is just a data-interchange format (http://www.json.org/).  There is no transactional semantic or anything that goes with it.

Comment: Yes its  interchange format..but just an idea..to create a new semantic format. eg like jsonSchema is for json schemas.